# Why doesnt taskbar-autohide work anymore, and how to workaround it

Tags: taskbar

I regularly see the windows 10 taskbar won't autohide, even though it's set to do so. This leads to app windows auto-sizing themselves to full screen size, putting critical ui parts (e.g. buttons/menus) behind the taskbar "that was not supposed to be there."

I assume the cause is other apps believing/reporting they have critical alerts I must address, in combination with faulty dismiss-code, ie those same apps fail to correctly clear their alert-status, causing windows to perpetually keep the  taskbar open.

How can I troubleshoot and fix this? What is really causing it?
And finally: Originally, this could be 'repaired' by clearing and reapplying the setting again. But in recent times, this repair no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are other potential causes to the taskbar remaining in it's unhidden state, specifically despite window boundary corresponding to it being supposedly hidden.  The one case I *do* know that would cause this is when an event has occurred in one of the inactive / minimized windows; usually, this would be visually indicated by the respective taskbar button flashing.  In this scenario, all you need to do is switch that particular Window into focus (active state), and the taskbar's hide behavior *should* return.

Comment: Yes (?), this is the known cause I believe. The problem I then see across machines and years, is that some applications seem to behave buggy in this regard. I believe I experience web browsers (Chrome) and Visual Studio do this (among others).